# Change label of title field for posts in the backend

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I am trying to add some HTML to the title label in the backend of WordPress.

**Attempt 1:**

I am using the following (simplified) function:

```
function change_post_titles() {
    global $post, $title, $action, $current_screen;

    $title = 'foo<br>bar';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'change_post_titles');
```

This works in the way that the label of the title field is indeed changed, however the HTML tags get encoded afterwards. This mean that the label looks like:

```
foo<br>bar
```

Instead of:

```
foo
bar
```

[image: Encoded HTML]

**Attempt 2:**

I also tried using a `gettext` filter, but that just completely filters (removes) the HTML.

```
add_filter('gettext', 'change_post_titles');
function change_post_titles( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    return $translated_text = 'foo<br>bar';
}
```

[image: Removed HTML]

Is there any way to change the title label (programmatically) in a way I can add HTML?

Comment: I don't think so. If you search `wp-admin/*.php` for `add-new-h2` (the class of the button afterwards) you'll see that the pages that use the title always render it as `echo esc_html( $title );`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add HTML to it.

For example, `wp-admin/edit.php` uses the following code:

```
<h1 class="wp-heading-inline">
<?php
echo esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->name );
?>
</h1>
```

As you can see, this uses the [esc_html()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) function. This prevents you from adding html code. This works this way for security reasons.

Answer (score -3):

```
function change_post_titles() {
    global $post, $title, $action, $current_screen;
    $title = "foo<br>bar";
    $title = str_replace('<br>', ' ', $title);
}
add_action('admin_head', 'change_post_titles');
```

Use this this will give the result you want. Please check it let me know for any doubts.